# /bin/sh: 1: compress: not found

Tags: bash, compression, tar

I'm very new in this world of bash scripting, so please be patient.

I'm following a basic guide to bash, repeating each script the guide shows.

This one:

```
#!/bin/bash
SRCD="/home/"
TGTD="/var/backups/"
OF=home-$(date +%Y%m%d).tgz
tar -cZf $TGTD$OF $SRCD
```

---

output THIS error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: compress: not found
tar: Child returned status 127
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Can someone explain to me what it means?

Comment: capital `Z` compress is referring to a now long-outdated compression method, whose program was just named `compress`. You don't have it installed. Use lowercase-z for zlib.

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: To get compress/uncompress on Debian/Ubuntu/family the package to install is `ncompress`, btw. Not sure about other OSes.

Answer (score 1):

From [the `tar` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar):

> -Z, --compress, --uncompress 
> filter the archive through compress

… and the error message:

> compress: not found

So you've told it to pass the output of `tar` through `compress` and it is telling you that `compress` isn't found (probably because you haven't installed it).

[People generally use gzip this century though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189273/whats-the-difference-between-gzip-and-compress) (or bzip2 which gives smaller files but is slower), not compress.

Comment: More than 15 years of the last century as well.

Comment: You will see .tar.xz, `-J, --xz`, as well.

Comment: I've largely abandoned bzip2 and xz for zstandard.